# String method replaceAll(String s,String replacement)

Tags: java, string

My friend is trying to finish his Computer Science project but one thing is preventing him from doing that: the String method replaceAll doesn't seem to be working correctly. He wants to remove all the instances of new line or a return (\n or a \r) and replace them with a couple spaces.

```
for(int c = 0; c<bible.size(); c++){
    bible.get(c).getForeign().replaceAll("\\n","          ");
    bible.get(c).getForeign().replaceAll("\\r","          ");
}
```

the code

```
bible.get(c).getForeign()
```

returns a String in a different language that is read in from a text file. Is there anything wrong with this code? It doesn't seem to replace the new lines with spaces. 
I checked the JavaDocumentation on the String class and for the

```
replaceAll(String str, String replacement);
```

they said that backslashes and dollar signs might make the returned string a little different. Is there another way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `'\n'` instead of "\\n"

Comment: Take a look at what `replaceAll` returns.

Comment: use `"\n"`, NOT `"\\n"`. `\n` means NEW LINE. Two backslashes represent 'backslash', so 'n' become plain character.

Answer (score 0):

`String` objects are immutable. The results are not stored in the original object. [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) returns a `String` object which you can store back like follows:

```
bible.get(c).setForeign(bible.get(c).getForeign().replaceAll("\\n","          "));
```

Comment: *How* did you manage to post an answer after the question was closed!? :O

Comment: Thats really strange co-incidence!! I started writing the answer when I saw the post. By the time I clicked 'Post Answer', it was closed but the answer was submitted.. Very rare occurence of this phenomenon!! :)

Comment: @luk2302 There is a grace period where it is still possible to post after closure. [It is actually quite long](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible).

Comment: @Tunaki thanks.. i wasn't aware of any grace period!